# Comparing two metrics from the same plot. Should I use a two-way ANOVA?

Tags: anova, experiment-design, blocking

I have the following design.

In each sampling plot, I measure food in four patches (BD, BF, OD, OF). From those I calculated preference for B trays and for D trays. So for every sampling plot I have two values.

I want to compare if preference for B trays are greater than the preference for D trays.

I used the mainly index to calculate preference, but for brevity let's assume I measure two ratios (BD+BF)/(OD+OF+BD+BF) and (BD+OD)/(OD+OF+BD+BF).

It seems to me that both ratios are dependent on one another, since both were calculated from the same 4 trays.

Can I call my design a randomized block, and answer my question with a two way ANOVA (preference value as dependent, type of ratio (B or D) as factor 1 and sampling plot as factor 2? Or should I use another analysis?